# How to fetch product name from orders table which contain product_id in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am unable to fetch the product name according to matching id but i am getting same name in table as shown below 
[this is the ordered list of products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HeYq.png)

Please check table for reference ill be showing below (order_list table)

[order_list table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUJOM.png)

Table products

[products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHflt.png)

My Controller

```
public function details($id)
{
    $orders = Order_model::find($id);        

    $Order_lists = Order_list::orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('order_id', '=', $id)->get();

    foreach($Order_lists as $order_list)
    {
        $prod_name = DB::table("products")->where('id', $order_list->product_id)->value('name');

    }
    $address = DB::table("delivery_address")->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    if(Auth::user()->role == 'customer')
    {
        return view('customer.orders.details',['Order_lists' => $Order_lists, 'orders' => $orders, 'address' => $address, 'prod_name' => $prod_name]);
    }

}
```

please Help me out as i am at learning stage and any help would be glad to hear thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is $prod_name is a single variable and you running it in loop. so it only replace every iteration and just get last iteration name. so if you want get every product name with $order_list , you can easily create Model for products table. then
create one to one Order_list. eg:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

```
class Order_list extends Model
{
   
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Products',"product_id");  //your model name and path
    }
}
```

then you can get all order list data with product like this:

```
$Order_lists = Order_list::orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('order_id', '=', $id)->with('products')->get();
```

product details should in `$Order_lists[0]->products->name`

edit: to run this in blade file

```
@foreach($Order_lists as $Order_list)
////other <td>s

    <td>{{$Order_list->products->name}}</td>


@endforeach
```

if above method is complex you can create separate array to name

```
 $prod_name =[];
 foreach($Order_lists as $order_list)
    {
        $prod_name[$order_list->product_id] = DB::table("products")->where('id',  $order_list->product_id)->value('name');

    }
```

then read it on blade file like this:

```
{{$prod_name[$order_list->product_id]}}
```

edit:
to print elements in second method you can use blade syntax.
first send veriables to .blade file
eg: view('your.blade.php,compact('Order_lists','prod_name'));

```
//then print in .blade file 

 @foreach($Order_lists as $Order_list)
        ////other <td>s
        
            <td>{{$prod_name[$order_list->product_id]}}</td>
        
        
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @Viduranga it worked and i understand this now correctly which i wasn't before !! But it didn't get worked with $Order_lists[0]->products->name as it just showed same names. i just placed it in <td> tag at blade by putting your code in controller, am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: i added just example $Order_lists[0]->products->name to get name. it get ony first element of array(start from 0). so to print all elements you have to run it using @foreach in blade file, i will update answer

Comment: @Viduranga please check this sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397069/laravel-get-product-name-product-table-from-product-id-order-item-table